# Wildcard Filter Array of Objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

How do I implement a wildcard filter on an array of objects? Even if filter works only on from the start, that should be fine. Should be able to filter on all properties of the object.

Should work in the same way as lodash filter works except for the fact that wildcard filter also works. Thanks.

```js
const sampleProducts = [{
    color: 'red',
    value: '#f00',
  },
  {
    color: 'green',
    value: '#0f0',
  },
  {
    color: 'blue',
    value: '#00f',
  },
  {
    color: 'cyan',
    value: '#0ff',
  },
  {
    color: 'magenta',
    value: '#f0f',
  },
  {
    color: 'yellow',
    value: '#ff0',
  },
  {
    color: 'black',
    value: '#000',
  },
];

const filteredResultsObj = {
  color: "red"
}

const filteredData = _.filter(sampleProducts, filteredResultsObj)

console.log(filteredData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

I can only do a whole word filter. Any advice on to implement a wild card filter such like this?

```js
const sampleProducts = [{
    color: 'red',
    value: '#f00',
  },
  {
    color: 'green',
    value: '#0f0',
  },
  {
    color: 'blue',
    value: '#00f',
  },
  {
    color: 'cyan',
    value: '#0ff',
  },
  {
    color: 'magenta',
    value: '#f0f',
  },
  {
    color: 'yellow',
    value: '#ff0',
  },
  {
    color: 'black',
    value: '#000',
  },
];

const filteredResultsObj = {color: "bl", value: '#f0'}

  const filteredData = _.filter(sampleProducts, filteredResultsObj)
    
// [{color: 'blue', value: '#00f'}, {color: 'black', value: '#000'}, {
    color: 'red',
    value: '#f00',
  }, {
    color: 'magenta',
    value: '#f0f',
  }]
```

Only from the start, the data should be filtered as in the above example. Shouldn't filter values with bl in the middle. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use the *function invoked per iteration* and test for a regular expression matching your patron. In this case a regular expression that match something starting with `bl`:

```js
const sampleProducts = [
  {color: 'red', value: '#f00'},
  {color: 'green', value: '#0f0'},
  {color: 'blue', value: '#00f'},
  {color: 'cyan', value: '#0ff'},
  {color: 'magenta', value: '#f0f'},
  {color: 'yellow', value: '#ff0'},
  {color: 'black', value: '#000'}
];

const regexp = /^bl/;

const filteredData = _.filter(sampleProducts, (o) => o.color.match(regexp));

console.log(filteredData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: at last the correct regex, most of the answers were missing `^`

Answer (score 0):

Without using lodash or underscore, your use case can be handled by this

```
const sampleProducts = [{
    color: 'red',
    value: '#f00',
  },
  {
    color: 'green',
    value: '#0f0',
  },
  {
    color: 'blue',
    value: '#00f',
  },
  {
    color: 'cyan',
    value: '#0ff',
  },
  {
    color: 'magenta',
    value: '#f0f',
  },
  {
    color: 'yellow',
    value: '#ff0',
  },
  {
    color: 'black',
    value: '#000',
  },
];

var strToMatch = 'bl';

var filtered = sampleProducts.filter(function(p) {
  var colorArray = p.color.split('');
  var colorToMatch = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < strToMatch.length; i++) {
    colorToMatch.push(colorArray[i]);
  }
  return strToMatch.toLowerCase() == colorToMatch.join('').toLowerCase()
})

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: How do I go about if my filter criteria is 'bl'? It should return the same results.

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use `RegExp` here.

```js
const sampleProducts = [{
    color: 'red',
    value: '#f00',
  },
  {
    color: 'green',
    value: '#0f0',
  },
  {
    color: 'blue',
    value: '#00f',
  },
  {
    color: 'cyan',
    value: '#0ff',
  },
  {
    color: 'magenta',
    value: '#f0f',
  },
  {
    color: 'yellow',
    value: '#ff0',
  },
  {
    color: 'black',
    value: '#000',
  },
];

const filterByValue = (coll, value) =>
  _.filter(coll, _.flow(
    _.values,
    _.partialRight(_.some, _.method('match', new RegExp(value, 'i')))
  ));

console.log(filterByValue(sampleProducts, 'r'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Damien. Is it possible I send in an object and filter works? Thanks. Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an alternative solution without regexp,
outside of box thinking, you can use substring function.

For instance, let's assume we search records in our data beginning with E letter and our data is E1, E2, E3, X1, X2, X3

```
let inputValue = 'E';
const data = ['E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3'];

const results = data.filter(d => d.substring(0, inputValue.length).toUpperCase() == inputValue.toUpperCase());

console.log(results);//Output: Array ["E1", "E2", "E3"]
```